# Uploaded file creation saving for future usage in GWT server side

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am new to GWT, I am facing some issue with file creation.

I am uploading a file from client side and want to store that file
in server side and parse it and create tables in database for the data
present in the file.

When I try to create a file at server side there is some file.io permission issue
App engine is not allowing me to create the file.

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

I did browse net, didn't find any solutions.

Thanks in Advance,
Pradeep

Comment: This looks more like an App Engine question. GWT is a client side framework.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store files to GAE as you do normally on a Web Server because you have no direct access to the file system. GAE gives you other ways to that using services.
There are two ways to store files on GAE :

- [BlobStore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/)
- [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/)

Comment: Thanks Sameer,but these are not for free,we might have to pay for using these.Dont we have any other way of  doing these things at all?

Comment: GAE is not free. You just have free quota for most if not all services. You will start to pay only when you exceed the free quota.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to give a try to [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/), it has a servlet and a set of FileItemFactory to store uploaded files in BlobStore, FileApi and MemCache.

Comment: Thanks for replying Manolo.But I might have to pay for using the above? Please let me know is there any way,reading the uploaded file content without storing the file? Which would serve the purpose.

Comment: Frontend might nt be free either. These file write restrictions are very well documented in appengine.

Comment: @user2784984 using a non-billing account, BlobStore has a limit of 5G, MemCache is for free, and Cloud Storage should have a limit (but I dont know). I would use the MemCacheFactory since storing in memory would not work because of the GAE constrains. The gwt-upload MemCacheFactory is able to store a file in small chunks in mem cache. The problem with memcache is that data could be lost after a while.